# Why is one joule equal to $V•C$?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, voltage

I was asked a question how much work is done on a 5C particle with the potential difference of 6V.

I knew the answer is 30J

But the solution says :-

1V=1J/1C
therefore
W=30J/1C•1C

How can we derive the second equation from the first?

Comment: $$6V = 6 J/1C \text{ , }5C = 5C$$ $$Work = 6 (J/1C) x 5 C$$  $$W = (30J/1C)\cdot 1C$$ $$ W= 30 (J/1C) \cdot 1C $$ it’s stupid but thats it

Comment: This isn't a derivation.  A volt was DEFINED as 1 J/C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last equation is correct but doesnt seem particularly useful. Work is charge times voltage. I dont know how whoever wrote the solution arrived at their answer, but it isnt a step you should need. Just multiply charge and voltage and be done.